# Show that $\{ x\in \mathbb{R}\::\:x\:^2\:∈\:\mathbb{N} \}$ and $N × N$ have the same cardinality.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I'm very puzzled on how to do this.

I know that $\{ x\in \mathbb{R}\::\:x\:^2\:∈\:\mathbb{N} \}$ can be written as $+\sqrt{1},-\sqrt{1},+\sqrt{2},-\sqrt{2},+\sqrt{3},-\sqrt{3}...$ but I'm unsure on how to write a bijection between $\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}$ and this set. I know I can first write a bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}$ but that seems just as hard. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you allowed to use Schroder-Bernstein?

Comment: A quick google will give you many answers but here's a hint for a possible approach: write $\mathbb N \times \mathbb N$ as a matrix and group the elements by where they appear on the diagonals: for each intger $j$ look at the pairs $(m,n)$ such that $m+n=j.$ Now play around with possible functions $\mathbb N\times \mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ using this grouping. You will discover the [Cantor Pairing Function](https://www.math.drexel.edu/~tolya/cantorpairing.pdf).